# To find adjacent sides of cube

Tags: java

I m trying to do a online problem about finding adjacent sides of a cube .The full question is at http://www.codechef.com/JULY15/problems/CHCUBE.
it gives correct answer to me, but when i submit it will get wrong answer.

heres my java code

```
 import java.util.*;

 class Cube {

     public static void main(String[] args)
         {
         long T;
         int blue = 0,black = 0,red=0,green=0,orange=0,yellow=0;

         Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
            T=input.nextLong();
            int pos=0,checked=0,answer=0;
         String colors[]=new String[6];
            while(T>0){

                for(int temp=0;temp<6;temp++)
                {
                colors[temp]=input.next();

                if(colors[temp].equals("blue"))
                {

                    blue++;
                    if(blue>2)
                        pos=temp;
                }
                else if(colors[temp].equals("black"))
                    {black++;
                    if(black>2)
                        pos=temp;
                    }
                else if(colors[temp].equals("yellow"))
                    {yellow++;
                    if(yellow>2)
                        pos=temp;
                    }
                else if(colors[temp].equals("orange"))
                    {orange++;
                    if(orange>2)
                        pos=temp;
                }
                else if(colors[temp].equals("green"))
                    {green++;
                    if(green>2)
                        pos=temp;
                }
                else if(colors[temp].equals("red"))
                    {red++;
                    if(red>2)
                        pos=temp;
                }
                }

                if(blue>2||black>2||green>2||yellow>2||red>2||orange>2)
                {       if(pos%2==0)
                    {
                        checked=(pos+2)%6;
                    }
                    else{


                        checked=(pos+1)%6;
                    }           


                    if(colors[pos].equals(colors[checked] )||colors[pos].equals(colors[(checked+1)%6]) )
                    {   
                                    if(colors[pos].equals(colors[(checked+3)%6]) ||colors[pos].equals(colors[(checked+2)%6]) )
                        {

                                            answer++;
                        }

                    }

                    }
                if(answer==1)
                    System.out.println("YES");
                else
                    System.out.println("NO");

                T--;
            }


         }



 }
```

Comment: What is the relation in your question between the adjacent sides of the cube and the colors in your code?

Comment: It sounds like your problem is more related to the grading scheme of the website, as opposed to the functionality. Have you confirmed the outputs to make sure they are correct and following the *exact* standards specified?

Comment: @Coder55 actually we have to find adjacent sides having same color.More clarification  at http://www.codechef.com/JULY15/problems/CHCUBE

Comment: @Sh4d0wsPlyr ya everything are ok. even my code runs fine for the given example.

Comment: Here's a hint: There's no way to paint 3 faces of a cube the same color without the faces being adjacent.  So, you just need to check for 3 of the same color.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc  we have to find sides having same colour and sharing a corner too.

Comment: Ok, let's say you paint the top and bottom green.  Tell me which of the faces remaining, left, right, front, or back, you can paint green without having any faces adjacent.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to model the whole thing as a graph.

A graph is a really flexible data structure, in this case 
you can also use all algorithms, because the problem size 
is so little.

The nodes of your graph are the sides, each node has to have 
an attribute `color` which is representing its color.

Each node also has a list of the adjacent sides( so we are 
implementing a graph with adjacent lists, not an adjacent matrix).

If you have built the graph you can begin to count adjacent sides with the same color. There are many different approaches, I think in your case it could be 
good to delete all nodes between not equally colored sides.

After that, you can count all the edges that are left in your graph. 
Since the graph is an undirected one, you have to divide the 
result by 2.

Note that this approach will not lead to huge main methods - you can solve and debug the problem much faster.

Comment: @Vishesh: Since you asked, you have one monolithic method.  Divide your code into methods and conquer the problem.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc we have to find sides having same colour and sharing a corner too.